# Twitter cover photo dimensions

Tags: twitter

Since today Twitter allows for a new cover photo to be uploaded.

Twitter recommends 1252x626 pixels and somewhere else also 1500x500p pixels, but when I upload an image of that size, only a part (top) of the image is shown, so some unwanted resizing seems to be done. I also checked this site: http://twitterheadersize.com/, but also the 520×260 recommended by that site does not show the full image in the header.

All I want to upload an image to Twitter and see that exact image as the coverphoto, but somehow that seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good information about the size of images.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

My recomendation is that you should design the 1500 x 500 image with a bleed area, i mean, test what portion of your design is croped for twitter and be sure that your more important content doesn´t get croped.

[image]